# Do compilers take the "status quo" when optimizations produced worse results?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

To my knowledge, when using optimizations there is a risk to face the "maybe will be worse" case (i.e. the performance will be degraded, or the code size will be higher, or both). However do compilers able to detect such cases and return to the "status quo" (i.e. fall back to the original non-optimized code) when optimizations produced worse results? Can someone give (if possible) a particular examples of what compilers (for example, gcc, Clang (LLVM), etc.) do in this case?

Comment: How would a compiler know that a particular optimisation had worse results? The compiler doesn't run the code.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that most compilers don't do exactly this (see @rici 's comment). There have been similar ideas though (and some might have been implemented in mainstream compilers), such as finding a near-optimal optimization ordering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In JIT compilers there is a thing called Deoptimization. Normally the compiler will optimize heavily assuming something, but during execution some of the assumption may fail. For example the compiler will assume the inmput of a function is always an integer and produce a highly efficient code for integer manipulation, but if, and such things happen in dynamic languages, the input is suddenly and array or a string, the code should revert. See v8 turbofan speculative optimizator for example.

For non JIT there is no way to deoptimize during runtime, but the compiler may create multiple execution paths. Your question is not fully logical because how would compiler know if it created unoptimal code? It can only use the same algorithm it used to do the optimization itself. That's probably why you are downwoted.